# How can i catch error? when i use redux-saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

How can i  catch error? when i use redux-saga?
if error occred in   const refreshresult  =   yield call(refresh);

i want to stop and throw this error action

i don't know what can i do

```
         yield put({
          type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
          error: err.response.data,
        });
```

how can i do that? how should i stop and send error action?

this is my code

```
        function getPostAPI(data) {
          return axiosInstace.post('/kakao/getpost', data);
        }

        function* getPost(action) {
          try {
          
            const result = yield call(getPostAPI, action.data);
            yield put({
              type: GETPOST_SUCCESS,
              data: result.data,
            });
          } catch (err) {
            if (err.response.data === 'jwtEx') {

         const refreshresult  =   yield call(refresh);  // <<<< if error occure refresh() i want to stop 

          
              yield put(action);
            } else {
              yield put({
                type: GETPOST_FAILURE,
                error: err.response.data,
              });
            }
          }
        }



        function* refresh() {
          try {
            const result = yield call(refreshAPI);
            yield AsyncStorage.setItem(
              'accesstoken',
              `${result.data.accessToken}`,
              () => {
                // console.log('accesstoken 재발급 저장 완료');
            
              },
            );
            yield put({
              type: REFRESH_SUCCESS,
              data: result.data,
            });
          } catch (err) {
          
            yield put({
              type: REFRESH_FAILURE,
              error: err.response.data,
            });
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you're doing it the right way. Try and catch will work.

Check out this link for more info [Redux-saga documentation](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/ErrorHandling/)